# How can the styles from a hashed css file be applied to an HTML document when the css file is NOT linked

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin

Im using webpack 3.7.1 and im sort of puzzled. When i run npm dist i do get an index.html and a app.css file within my dist folder. Thats expected.

Now if open the index.html on a web brower locally i can see that all the styles on app.css are applied to index. But what i cannot understand is how
these styles are applied when clearly on index.html, the file app.css is not linked at all, but what it is linked is the hashed named version of it (e.g. app.css?a8ade0dbcb0f4985edc3).

I was thinking maybe the styles were being served from memory or something so i uploaded the whole dist folder to my server. Cause there is NO app.css?a8ade0dbcb0f4985edc3 file on the dist folder. So that tells me the styles should not be applied cause a file with that name does not exists. But then when i visited the website on different computers and browsers, the styles from app.css are being reflected, even if this file is NOT linked on the HTML of the index.html file. (what is linked is the hashed named version).

So HOW on earth can this be possible? I already did a search for the string 
?a8ade0dbcb0f4985edc3 within my project (within the dist folder) but it is NOT anywhere but on the index.html file.

Can someone please explain to me what is happening here.

The files within the dist folder and on the server are:

```
app.a8ade0dbcb0f4985edc3.bundle.js
app.css
contact.a8ade0dbcb0f4985edc3.bundle.js
contact.html
contact.html
```

This is the content of index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <link href="app.css?a8ade0dbcb0f4985edc3" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body> 
    <h1>beautiful day</h1> <img src="img/webpack-22.ext" alt="Webpack Logo">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.a8ade0dbcb0f4985edc3.bundle.js?a8ade0dbcb0f4985edc3"></script>
</body>
```

And this is the content my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');


//Checking if prod or dev mode
const isProd = process.argv.indexOf('-p') !== -1; //this returns true or false
//if dev mode then we create the css of our app inline
const cssDev = ['style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader'];

//production config for our css
const cssProd = ExtractTextPlugin.extract( [
    // {loader: 'style-loader'},
    {loader: 'css-loader'},
    {loader: 'sass-loader'}
]);

//if this variable is true we use cssProd otherwise we use cssDev
const cssConfig = isProd ? cssProd : cssDev;


module.exports = {

    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js',
        contact: './src/contact.js'
    },
    output: {
           path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
           // filename: 'app.bundle.js' // just one output file
            filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js' //multiple output files
    },



    module: {
        rules: [

            //THIS IS THE FIRST RULE
            { test: /\.scss$/,
                // since this is an array of loaders we use use instead of loadernpm install babel-preset-env --save-dev

                use: cssConfig //this will return either the content of cssDev ir cssProd
            },

            //THIS IS THE SECOND RULE
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" },

            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ['html-loader']
            },

            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|gif)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].ext',
                        outputPath: 'img/',
                        // publicPath: 'img/' //not needed cause We specify public path once in the output
                        // section and it applies to the whole project.
                    }
                }

            }

        ]
    },

    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        compress: true,
        port: 8080,
        open: true
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        {
            minify: {collapseWhitespace:false},
            hash: true,
            excludeChunks: ['contact'],
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
            {
                minify: {collapseWhitespace:false},
                hash: true,
                chunks: ['contact'],
                template: './src/contact.html',
                filename:'contact.html'

            }),



        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'app.css',
            disable: !isProd,
            allChunks: true


        })

    ]

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this on a random Google search, so figured I might answer.

A question mark in a URL indicates a query parameter. E.g. in the URL `https://example.com/users?filter=male`, regardless of what you write after the `?`, the request is about the resource `https://example.com/users`.

Frameworks like webpack use a cache busting technique where they append a valueless query parameter (e.g. `?a8ade0dbcb0f4985edc3`) to the URL. This parameter changes with every build and forces the browser to send a new request and fetch the latest version of that resource. In your case, it simply ends up serving the latest version of `app.css`.